# Asmx web service sometimes won't respond

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis-7, asmx

I have a .asmx web service on `SharedHosting` server which won't respond in some cases. It works  when suddenly it stopped working and doesn't work for a couple hours and it work againg. When it stopped working I upload web.config file ( wirhout any change in file, just upload and overwrite file wia ftp) on server and web service starts behave normaly until next time when it stopped working.

Web.config

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
       <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

What I'm doing wrong? I assume it's problem with web.config file. Probably it's missing some configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like your web service is buggy. By uploading the `web.config` you will be restarting the IIS apppool (effectivly doing this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732742(v=ws.10).aspx), this will restart the service so this is why it works when you change/upload a new web.config. You need to diagnose what the issue is with the service, **the web.config isn't the problem**

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm going to check web service, it could be a memory leak.

Comment: the best way to say thank you is to accept an answer or an upvote!

Comment: I know, but I don't have enough reputation to vote, it requires 15 reputation. I'll vote when earn required reputation.

Comment: If you accept an answer you get reputation! Anyway, glad it helped

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not a problem with your web.config file.
When you upload a new web.config, you cause IIS to reset your application.

This does solve your problem, but is not your root cause.
Implement logging to keep checks on the memory your application is using.

An application reset can solve a lot of memory issues.
I am guessing you have a memory leak, that after a few hours cause your application to hang.

Comment: Thanks for answer. When I think it could be problem with web service.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the application and system event logs on the machine on which the service is running, for clues as to why the service is falling over

Comment: Thanks for answer. Plesk on web server is temporarily unavailable. I'll try later.

Answer (score 0):

I had had the same problem. The reason is probably your data layer. You should check all methods and check if you are properly disposing the connections with a `using` block. To test this theory, open your SQL Profile, and look for "audit logout" several times.